# Trying to make a discord bot that forwards channel messages

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

I am trying to create a discord bot that takes announcements from all important servers I am in, and condenses it all into one easy to manage channel in my own personal server. I am part of a good 10-20 servers I have been active in for some time, and I recently picked up hours at work so now don't have time to switch servers consistently anymore. Would make it a lot easier to stay in the know if I could have an easy or at least manageable system.

Is this possible? And if so, could someone point me in the direction of what I need to do or know in creating it? I have created discord bots before but I am intermediate at it.

Thank you for your time!

I am able to manage basic functions such as setting up node, npm, discord.js, index.js, config.json, eslint. I just do not know where I would start in fetching a channel to a server that my bot is not in.

Answer (score 0):

#### Attempt number 1:

1. Set up a new Discord bot application on the Discord Developer Portal.
2. Invite the bot to all the important servers you want to monitor.
3. Set up your bot using Discord.js to listen incoming messages and forward them to your own server.

**The problem:** To invite your bot to a Discord server that you don't own, you'll need the "Manage Server" or "Administrator" permission on that server. Without these permissions, you won't be able to invite the bot.

---

#### Attempt number 2:

Using your own account.

1. Join to all the important servers you want to monitor.
2. Set up your account using Discord.js to listen incoming messages and forward them to your own server.

**The problem:** The official [Discord.js](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js) library does not support or endorse the use of self-bots, which are bots that utilize a user account token to perform actions on behalf of a user.

but

There is an unofficial discord.js fork called [discord.js-selfbot-v13](https://github.com/aiko-chan-ai/discord.js-selfbot-v13) that allows you to do that. By using this library, you can utilize your account as a bot and accomplish whatever you want.